# XCode Google Maps App, Open with users location + Search bar

Tags: xcode

I'm new to XCode and really need help. I've created a map full of markers and call outs which I'm happy with and understand fully. Now I really want to have the map center on the users GPS location instead of a fixed Latitude and Longitude. Is this possible?

Also is it possible to add in a search bar widget above the map so if a user wants to check out a certain area they can instead of having to scroll there. So when the user types in an area it will take them there whilst the markers remain on the map. (possibly the information of the areas will draw from googles map database).

Is this all possible?

Answer (score 1):

Drag "Map View" to your view on storyboard. when ctrl is held down, drag the mouse pointer from "Map View" to the class. 
create iVar for it as mapView (or anything you wish)

[mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];

Above code will always set the user location(blue dot)  to the current location fetched by the GPS.

* For Search BAR ***
 NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", "FECTH TEXT FROM SEARCH BAR" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

urlString will return latitude, longitude details. With this detail, you can show the location where the user wants to go.